# babelHelpers is not defined when using an old package

Tags: javascript, vue.js, d3.js, webpack, babeljs

Currently, I'm working on a vuetify v1.5 project. One of my dependency package (d3-flextree) does not work in the case of the 'babelHelpers is not defined' error.
What I've found says: "Use transform-runtime instead of the external-helpers plugin".
My .babelrc file is:

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "stage-2"],
  "plugins": [
    "transform-runtime",
    "transform-async-to-generator"
    
  ],
  "comments": false
}
```

but .babelrc in ./node_module/d3-flextree is:

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "es2015",
      { "modules": false }
    ]
  ],
  "plugins": ["external-helpers"]
}
```

Should I override ./node_module/d3-flextree/.babelrc? if yes, how?
Is there any webpack trick?

My package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.3",
    "d3": "^5.7.0",
    "d3-flextree": "^2.1.1",
    "d3-flextree-v4": "^1.0.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.6.3",
    "hchs-vue-charts": "^1.2.8",
    "html-loader": "^1.1.0",
    "html-webpack-externals-plugin": "^3.8.0",
    "html2canvas": "^1.0.0-rc.5",
    "ts-loader": "^7.0.5",
    "vue": "^2.5.11",
    "vue-color": "^2.7.1",
    "vue-grid-layout": "^2.3.8",
    "vue-i18n": "^8.22.1",
    "vue-input-autowidth": "^1.0.10",
    "vue-quill-editor": "^3.0.6",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.1",
    "vue-server-renderer": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.11",
    "vue2-editor": "^2.10.2",
    "vuedraggable": "^2.23.2",
    "vuetify": "^1.5.24",
    "vuex": "^3.0.1",
    "vuex-router-sync": "^5.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "aspnet-webpack": "^2.0.1",
    "babel-core": "^6.21.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.10",
    "babel-plugin-external-helpers": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-async-to-generator": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.15.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-register": "^6.18.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.4.1",
    "cross-env": "^3.1.3",
    "css-loader": "^0.26.4",
    "event-source-polyfill": "^0.0.7",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.0-rc",
    "file-loader": "^0.9.0",
    "jquery": "^2.2.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^1.3.1",
    "sass-loader": "^4.1.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.2",
    "stylus": "^0.54.5",
    "stylus-loader": "^3.0.2",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.3",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "vue-loader": "^13.6.0",
    "webpack": "^2.2.0",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.12.2"
  }
```

Comment: If I change  ./node_module/d3-flextree/.babelrc to use 'transform-runtime' manually the problem will vanish. In the case of CI pipeline, I cannot use this trick

Answer (score 0):

I've found a trick.
There is a [CDN file for 'd3-flextree'](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/d3-flextree@2.0.0/build/d3-flextree.min.js). Just copy it into a file in the project and then replace the original npm package.

```
- import * as d3flex from "d3-flextree"
+ import * as d3flex from "../statics/scripts/d3-flextree.min"
```